# Update Facebook Login Fragment inside a drawer onLogin in Android

Tags: facebook, android-fragments

From the title itself, how could I update the Facebook Login fragment inside a drawer? Inside an active layout, the Facebook fragment itself is being updated.

BUT, when you placed it inside a drawer, it is not.

Once you login with the facebook fragment, the ativity is just being resumed,
with the drawer being opened and the facebook fragment remaining as is.

Does anybody encountered or have a working solution for this? 
Even a quick workaround would do do counter this for me.